# SpringMVC/SpringBoot JSON Array with Integer and String

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, flot

I am attempting to replace an old ASP page that returns JSON which fills a flot chart. (http://www.flotcharts.org/)

My issue is this,

The old ASP page returns this JSON:

```
{"xaxis":{"ticks":[[100,"Location1"],[200,"Location2"],[300,"Location3"]]}}
```

As you can see, "ticks" contains a list of arrays with 2 members. The first member of each array is a number, the second is a string.

The closest I have been able to get with SpringMVC/SpringBoot is this:

```
{"xaxis":{"ticks":[["100","Location1"],["200","Location2"],["300","Location3"]]}}
```

You'll notice that the numbers are actually strings.

Here is the Controller I am using:

```
@Controller
public class GraphWebController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getXAxisData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Map<String, XAxisData> getXAxisData(Model model) {

        String[] location1 =  new String[]{"100", "Location1"};
        String[] location2 =  new String[]{"200", "Location2"};
        String[] location3 =  new String[]{"300", "Location3"};

        List<String[]> xAxisLocations = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        xAxisLocations.add(location1);
        xAxisLocations.add(location2);
        xAxisLocations.add(location3);

        XAxisData xaxis = new XAxisData(xAxisLocations);

        Map<String, XAxisData> xAxisData = new HashMap<String, XAxisData>();
        xAxisData.put("xaxis", xaxis);

        return xAxisData;

    }
}

public class XAxisData {

    private List<String[]> ticks;

    public XAxisData(List<String[]> ticks) {
        this.ticks = ticks;
    }

    public List<String[]> getTicks() {
        return ticks;
    }

    public void setTicks(List<String[]> ticks) {
        this.ticks = ticks;
    }
}
```

I tried changing the String arrays to Object arrays, and changing the quoted numbers to actual integers but then I get the following error that Object cannot be cast to String.

```
<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Tue May 26 14:28:55 EDT 2015</div><div>There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).</div><div>Could not write JSON: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String; (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap[&quot;xaxis&quot;]-&gt;springmvc.graph.XAxisData[&quot;ticks&quot;]-&gt;java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String; (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap[&quot;xaxis&quot;]-&gt;springmvc.graph.XAxisData[&quot;ticks&quot;]-&gt;java.util.ArrayList[0])</div></body></html>
```

**How do I get the exact same output as the old ASP page?**

I am fairly open to hacky solutions at this point. The less hacky the better though. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show `XAxisData`?

Comment: Also, please post the exact change you made with its full stack trace.

Comment: Also, also, are you using Jackson (which verison?) or Gson for serializing JSON?

Comment: Updated question with XAxisData, and full stack trace. 
In the stack trace, I see that it references Jackson. I will try to find out which version. It is possible it is a default version that came with SpringBoot, or something.

Comment: You can tell from the package name, `fasterxml` is version 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an `XAxisData` class like follows

```
class XAxisData {
    private List<Object[]> ticks;

    public XAxisData(List<Object[]> xAxisLocations) {
        this.ticks = xAxisLocations;
    }

    public List<Object[]> getTicks() {
        return ticks;
    }

    public void setTicks(List<Object[]> ticks) {
        this.ticks = ticks;
    }
}
```

you can use

```
Object[] location1 = new Object[] { 100, "Location1" };
Object[] location2 = new Object[] { 200, "Location2" };
Object[] location3 = new Object[] { 300, "Location3" };

List<Object[]> xAxisLocations = new ArrayList<>();
xAxisLocations.add(location1);
xAxisLocations.add(location2);
xAxisLocations.add(location3);

XAxisData xaxis = new XAxisData(xAxisLocations);

Map<String, XAxisData> xAxisData = new HashMap<String, XAxisData>();
xAxisData.put("xaxis", xaxis);
```

This produces

```
{"xaxis":{"ticks":[[100,"Location1"],[200,"Location2"],[300,"Location3"]]}}
```

Though I would recommend you change the `Map` to a POJO if you don't plan on having any other dynamic root JSON fields.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried when I said I changed The String array to Object array. This gives me the Object to String casting error.

Comment: It's not enough to change the `XAxisData`, you need to change the handler method's code. Did you do that? This works fine for me.

Comment: I did try this, but I must not have restarted my SpringBoot app properly or something. I've double checked, and your answer is exactly what I had tried before. You sir are a king amongst men. Thanks for your help!